# anaconda-navigator fails to launch, ImportError. Install was previously fine

Tags: python, anaconda

After functioning fine for nearly a year my Anaconda Navigator has stopped functioning after my Windows11 device updated itself overnight (unprompted, thank you Microsoft.)
Update: *2024-02 Cumulative Update for Windows 11 Version 23H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5034765)*

It's unclear whether this is the direct cause, or whether an unrelated matter triggered the issue.

Jupyter Lab, which I use through Anaconda Navigator, was open at the time.

When opening the Navigator shortcut, a couple command prompt windows pop up (as was the case prior to today), but the navigator simply does not start. No error messages are displayed through this approach.

What I've already tried:
[Most of the steps documented here](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/troubleshooting/#navigator-issues). [Previous link](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/navigator/troubleshooting/)

- Deleted the `.condarc` file.
- Launch `anaconda-navigator` directly through Anaconda Prompt.
- Manually update with `conda update -n base anaconda-navigator`
- Updated urllib3 with `conda update urllib3` (reason below)
- Executed `conda remove -n base anaconda-navigator` &
  `conda install -n base anaconda-navigator`
- Restarted my device prior to and after all these steps.

Launching `anaconda-navigator` through Anaconda Prompt does display an error, and this error has changed with the steps taken above.

The original error was [related to Pydantic, with this link attached.](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings) This error is no longer displayed.

The current Error is related to urllib3, full trace below:

```
(base) C:\Users\user>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 30, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 21, in <module>
    import binstar_client
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .requests_ext import NullAuth
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\requests_ext.py", line 11, in <module>
    from urllib3.filepost import choose_boundary, iter_fields
ImportError: cannot import name 'iter_fields' from 'urllib3.filepost' (C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\filepost.py)
```

urllib3 version: 2.1.0

pydantic version: 2.6.1

Looks like iter_fields might be deprecated. Would downgrading urllib3 be sufficient to get Anaconda Navigator working again?

Comment: [This user encountered a very similar error.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76619734/)

Comment: While the error above was near equivalent, the cause is clearly not. In the example above Anaconda attempts to import urllib3 from a different directory, which is not the case here. This appears to also have been an [issue in anaconda-navigator more widely previously, though it should be resolved](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-client/issues/654), especially given I just force-updated.

Comment: Resolved this specific issue by downgrading with: `conda install urllib3==1.26.15` within Anaconda Prompt. This is a workaround, and not a permanent solution. `conda install urllib3<2` would've been preferable, but that too caused issues ("The system cannot find the file specified"). Leaving the question open in case a more optimal answer is found.

Comment: The issue you linked to is for `anaconda-client`. Although related, the actual issue you faced regarding `anaconda-navigator` (tied to https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/13351) is still unresolved (as of now)